# Errors after update: "File already exists error list-utils-pkg.el"

Tags: init-file, files

When I relaunched emacs after updating some packages, I had an error:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (file-already-exists "File already exists "/home/linevich/.emacs.d/elpa-24-3-1-x86-64-pc-linux-gnu/list-utils-20140508.1341/list-utils-pkg.el")
  write-region("(define-package \"list-utils\" \"20140508.1341\" \"List-manipulation utility functions\" (quote nil))\n" nil "/home/linevich/.emacs.d/elpa-24-3-1-x86-64-pc-linux-gnu/list-utils-20140508.1341/list-utils-pkg.el" nil nil nil excl)
  package-unpack-single("list-utils" "20140508.1341" "List-manipulation utility functions" nil)
  package-download-single(list-utils "20140508.1341" "List-manipulation utility functions" nil)
  package-download-transaction((ucs-utils list-utils pcache persistent-soft font-utils unicode-fonts))
  package-install(unicode-fonts)
  ergoemacs-component-struct--ensure(unicode-fonts)
  ergoemacs-component-struct--apply-inits()
  run-hooks(ergoemacs-mode-startup-hook)
  ergoemacs-mode(1)
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "/home/linevich/.emacs.d/init.el" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 524
  load-with-code-conversion("/home/linevich/.emacs.d/init.el" "/home/linevich/.emacs.d/init.el" t t)
  load("/home/linevich/.emacs.d/init" t t)
  #[0 "\205\262
```

I tried to remove this file, and had the next one traceback:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (file-already-exists "Файл вже існує" "/home/linevich/.emacs.d/elpa-24-3-1-x86-64-pc-linux-gnu/pcache-20150125.1653/pcache-pkg.el")
  write-region("(define-package \"pcache\" \"20150125.1653\" \"persistent caching for Emacs\" (quote ((eieio \"1.3\"))))\n" nil "/home/linevich/.emacs.d/elpa-24-3-1-x86-64-pc-linux-gnu/pcache-20150125.1653/pcache-pkg.el" nil nil nil excl)
  package-unpack-single("pcache" "20150125.1653" "persistent caching for Emacs" ((eieio (1 3))))
  package-download-single(pcache "20150125.1653" "persistent caching for Emacs" ((eieio (1 3))))
  package-download-transaction((ucs-utils list-utils pcache persistent-soft font-utils unicode-fonts))
  package-install(unicode-fonts)
  ergoemacs-component-struct--ensure(unicode-fonts)
  ergoemacs-component-struct--apply-inits()
  run-hooks(ergoemacs-mode-startup-hook)
  ergoemacs-mode(1)
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "/home/linevich/.emacs.d/init.el" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 524
  load-with-code-conversion("/home/linevich/.emacs.d/init.el" "/home/linevich/.emacs.d/init.el" t t)
  load("/home/linevich/.emacs.d/init" t t)
  #[0 "\205\262
```

When I removed this file too, I had the same error as at the beginning "list-utils-pkg.el" exists.
How to fix this?
My config is messy, but I think that the problematic package is ergoemacs which tries to install some packages.
[Config here](https://bitbucket.org/snippets/linevich/894n4).
P.S Sorry for my English :)

Comment: Have you tried contacting [erogemacs](https://ergoemacs.github.io/bug-report.html) with the error message? Xah Lee usually finds workarounds if you can provide debugger messages.

Comment: Thanks for advice, I've already done it. [issue](https://github.com/ergoemacs/ergoemacs-mode/issues/350)

Comment: One last suggestion, a while back something similar happened and I had to delete the offending packages and reinstall them so old code got cleaned out. Later I found out it was related to math fonts. Perhaps you can try cleaning out while you wait for ergoemacs to respond.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the [solution on GitHub](https://github.com/ergoemacs/ergoemacs-mode/issues/350):

> This seems like a package management issue.
>   I would delete the elpa versions of ergoemacs-mode and list-utils and then use the stable melpa repository. This require updating your config to:

`(add-to-list 'package-archives
         ;'("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/")
             '("melpa-stable" . "http://stable.melpa.org/packages/")
         '("marmalade" ."http://marmalade-repo.org/packages/")
         )`

> Then re-downloading the stable ergoemacs-mode.

Comment: Please summarize the answer. Link-only answers are typically closed.